# Same button outputting different sounds

Tags: java, android

This is the code I have at the moment.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_earthbound);

    int charNo = (Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_CHARNO);
    Earthbound character = Earthbound.chars[charNo];

    ImageView photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
    photo.setImageResource(character.getImageResourceId());
    photo.setContentDescription(character.getName());

    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setText(character.getName());

    TextView desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc);
    desc.setText(character.getDesc());

    Button voice_btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.voice_btn);
    voice_btn.setContentDescription(character.getName());
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.snd_se_narration_characall_Ness);
    final MediaPlayer mmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.snd_se_narration_characall_Lucas);
    voice_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            mp.start();
            mmp.start();
        }
    });
```

I essentially have two activities, the first one being that the user can choose the list view option "Earthbound", a Java class which lists the characters, and an activity displaying the characters bio. The second activity has one button, **but this button will change sounds depending on which character the user picked.** This is where I am stuck.

This is the Java class if it helps:

```
private String name;
private String desc;
private int imageResourceId;
private int voiceId;

public Earthbound(String name, String desc, int imageResourceId, int voice){
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    this.voiceId = voiceId;
}
public static final Earthbound[] chars = {
        new Earthbound("Ness", "Ness is the silent main protagonist of EarthBound (Mother 2 in Japan), " +
                "and is analogous to Ninten and Lucas in their respective games. He greatly enjoys baseball; " +
                "not only are most of his weapons various types of baseball bats, " +
                "but he can also equip several baseball caps. ", R.drawable.ness, R.raw.snd_se_narration_characall_Ness),
        new Earthbound("Lucas", "Lucas is the central character of Mother 3, out of seven main characters total. " +
                "(Lucas, Kumatora, Duster, Boney, Claus, Flint, and Salsa). He is from Tazmily Village. " +
                "He is the gentle twin of Claus. ", R.drawable.lucas, R.raw.snd_se_narration_characall_Lucas),
};

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public int getImageResourceId() {
    return imageResourceId;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.name;
}

public int getVoiceId() {
    return voiceId;
}
```

Comment: Why the "JavaScript" tag? No other mention of JS in your question, so I'm going to remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use an if or switch statement to determine which sound plays?

```
if ((character.getName().compareTo("Ness")) == 0)
            mp.start();
else
            mmp.start();
```

something like this ought to work.

Comment: `compareTo == 0`? Why not `.equals()`?

Comment: I used `.equals()` for a class assignment and my professor said that it would be better to use `.compareTo()` for Strings. Two different professors actually told me the same thing on the same day.

Comment: I think they assumed you were trying "equals" an in `==`. The source code for `String#compareTo` says *The result is zero if the strings are equal; `compareTo` returns 0 exactly when the `equals(java.lang.Object)` method would return true.*

Answer (score 0):

If you just need choose a sound to play, you can set your sound resource to you `Earthbound`, Others use your code and need not know which resource to selected.

```
private String name;
private String desc;
private int imageResourceId;
private int voiceId;

public Earthbound(String name, String desc, int imageResourceId, int voice){
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    this.voiceId = voiceId;
}
public static final Earthbound[] chars = {
        new Earthbound("Ness", "Ness is the silent main protagonist of EarthBound (Mother 2 in Japan), " +
                "and is analogous to Ninten and Lucas in their respective games. He greatly enjoys baseball; " +
                "not only are most of his weapons various types of baseball bats, " +
                "but he can also equip several baseball caps. ", R.drawable.ness, R.raw.snd_se_narration_characall_Ness),
        new Earthbound("Lucas", "Lucas is the central character of Mother 3, out of seven main characters total. " +
                "(Lucas, Kumatora, Duster, Boney, Claus, Flint, and Salsa). He is from Tazmily Village. " +
                "He is the gentle twin of Claus. ", R.drawable.lucas, R.raw.snd_se_narration_characall_Lucas),
};

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public int getImageResourceId() {
    return imageResourceId;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.name;
}

public int getVoiceId() {
    return voiceId;
}

public int getMediaResourceId() {
    return TextUtils.equals(name, "Ness") ? R.raw.snd_se_narration_characall_Ness : R.raw.snd_se_narration_characall_Lucas;
}
```

Then

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, character.getMediaResourceId());
voice_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: How about for handling more than 2 characters?

Comment: @DericWu  You can add a `type` and then add `switch case` in `getMediaResourceId()`